# Sum of row data in datatable with double quotes

Tags: c#, datatable

I want get the total of a column in a datatable which has rows with double quotes.

[datatable image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEJVK.jpg)

I want to add both rows in LINES_DISPENSED_AMOUNT1 column.

Comment: Welcome to SO - please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this has C# tag, I would suggest you fetch all records, then in C# loop over the values and do a `value.Trim('"')`. Parse values to `int` and do a `LINQ` query `sum()`.

Comment: I would do a int.TryParse(stringValue, out value) since you can't just cast string to int
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785351/input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format-converting-string-to-int